# Azure Data Flow ( Data Flow) - First row field value as custom field to remaining rows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am creating DataFlow in ADF.  my requirement is to read first row one field value and make it as session id for rest of the rows.  I looked into the expressions but didn't find much functions that will help on this.

ex: Source file in blob :---------------

```
 time               ,phone
 2020-01-31 10:00:00,1234567890
 2020-01-31 10:10:00,9876543219

 Target should be :-----------------

 SessionID          , time, Phone
 20200131100000,2020-01-31 10:00:00,1234567890
 20200131100000,2020-01-31 10:10:00,9876543219
```

SessionIID is a derived column. i need to read first row of time and remember that time and apply to all rows for sessionID.

```
How to read first row time value and keep it in global variable ? 

any inputs are appreciated.
```

Comment: Does my answer achieve your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Lookup` activity in pipeline(check First row only option) and pass `time` value to Data Flow parameter. Then use `Derived Column` transform in Data Flow to add `SessionID` column.

Details:

1. check First row only option in `Lookup` activity
   [image]
2. use this expression to get your expected value:

`@replace(replace(replace(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.time,'-',''),' ',''),':','')`

[image]

3.pass value of this variable to parameter in Data Flow.
[image]

4.add Session column in Data Flow.
[image]